# KNEX Undefined binding(s) detected when compiling SELECT query

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js, bookshelf.js

```
var knex = require('knex')(config);
var bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);
var SKU = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'skus',

});
SKU.where('id', undefined).fetch().then(function (skus) {
    if (skus) console.log(skus.toJSON());
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```

It throws

```
Undefined binding(s) detected when compiling SELECT query.
```

It is working fine with 0.11.5, it stopped working with 0.11.6 onwards. I am pointing to 0.13.0 right now.

```
useNullAsDefault: true
```

works fine with insert queries but not select queries. Is there any flag i should pass to resolve this error?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`.where('id', undefined)` does not mean anything in SQL. You cannot be querying something that is not there.

Maybe you wanted to query `where id IS NULL`? With knex it can be done like this: `.whereNull('id')`

With earlier knex versions it would have been just ignored, but starting from 0.12.x.

So to have equivalent functionality with newer (and actually it is compatible with older < 0.12 versions too) knex versions you should do:

```
SKU.fetch().then(function (skus) {
    if (skus) console.log(skus.toJSON());
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Unless bookshelf is adding some extra magic there...

The `useNullAsDefault: true` option Is used only for when inserting multiple rows in one insert. It does not make sense to use it unless you are using sqlite (check last example of http://knexjs.org/#Builder-insert).

Comment: This error can occur if the Knex query relies on a parameter value that's supplied using JSON, and the JSON is invalid in some way. E.g you might send an HTTP POST request, and the request handler performs a Knex query based on the HTTP body. If you don't specifying that the POST body is JSON (`Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8`), or the JSON is invalid, you may see the error.

Comment: Yes, there are literally infinite ways to provide undefined values to knex.

Comment: Must say this is a very annoying error! `where({id: undefined}` shouldn't result in an "undefined column `id`" error message.

Comment: @ankush981 actually it should throw the error. Historically many knex apps had really huge security holes when `undefined` filters were just ignored and instead of returning / modifying correct row, bunch of unrelated rows were returned/modified.

Answer (score 3):

## parameter mismatch in payload

the parameter which sql query is expecting and the parameter you sending in requestbody is not matching.
in my case sql was expecting parameter "gradeId" but in requestBody i was sending "postId"